# How to print out an array as questions and answers

Tags: php, arrays

If I have the following array

```
$arrays = $cdo->rows();

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => what is the name of you ?
            [1] => Reham
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Where did you came from ?
            [1] => earth
        )
 )
```

Using PHP language how can i print this like a question and answer

My try since Iam not good in PHP was

```
foreach ($arrays as $arr){
//print_r($arr);
  foreach (arr as $a){
   echo $a  . "<br />";
  }
}
```

But results like

```
what is the name of you ?
Reham
Where did you came from ?
earth
```

So I'm unable to know where is the question and where is the answer, as I'm going to insert it into database so am i supposed to something like

```
foreach ($arrays as $arr){
//print_r($arr);
  foreach (arr as $q => $a){
   echo "Question : " . $q  . " | Answer : " . $a . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I fully understood what you want. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$array = [
    [
       'what is the name of you ?',
       'Reham'
    ],
    [
        'Where did you came from ?',
        'earth'
    ]
];

foreach($array as $arr) {
    echo $arr[0] . '<br>' . $arr[1] . '<br>';
}
```

Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: works perfect :) thanks a lot .. i should learn much about `arrays`

Comment: @RehamFahmy glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not really good to deal with, it's only an indexed array, you should use a multidimensional.

But you can just use indexes :

```
foreach ($arrays as $arr) {
    echo $arr[0]; // question
    echo $arr[1]; // answer
}
```

Comment: works fine :) never thought that would be easy like that way .. thanks a lot .. i should learn much about `arrays`

Comment: Yes, but I said, you should use multidimensionnal arrays, using indexes is not good since they can change